# How to optimize this method and avoid foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, optimization, eloquent

I have the following models in my Laravel application: Course, Event, Student, Enrolment, Attendance.

- a Course hasMany Events.
- when a Student is enrolled in a Course, an Enrolment is generated, so a course hasMany Enrolments.
- a Student hasMany Attendance records.
- an Attendance record belongsTo an Event and belongsTo a Student.

I want to retrieve the list of courses which have at least one student with less attendance records than the expected total number of events in the course. For instance, if a course has 10 events, I need to get all courses with at least one student having less than the 10 expected attendance records for these events.

As a temporary solution, I'm using a nested foreach loop in my Course model:

```
public function getEventsWithExpectedAttendanceAttribute()
{
    return $this->events()->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('exempt_attendance', '!=', true);
        $query->where('exempt_attendance', '!=', 1);
        $query->orWhereNull('exempt_attendance');
    })->where('start', '<', Carbon::now(env('COURSES_TIMEZONE'))->toDateTimeString())->get();
}

public function getMissingAttendanceAttribute()
{
    $eventsWithMissingAttendanceCount = 0;

    // loop through every event supposed to have attendance
    foreach ($this->events_with_expected_attendance as $event)
    {
        // loop through every student
        foreach ($this->enrollments as $enrollment)
        {
            // if the student has no attendance record for this event
            if (Attendance::where('student_id', $enrollment->student_id)->where('event_id', $event->id)->count() == 0)
            {
    // count one and break loop
            $eventsWithMissingAttendanceCount++;
            break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $eventsWithMissingAttendanceCount;
}
```

But this is really not pretty and also terribly inefficient, performance-wise. However, I have been unable to find a better solution so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: here is db schema

```
CREATE TABLE `courses` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `course_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `enrollments` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `course_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `attendances` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `event_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql. If that sounds like a reasonable idea, delete the above and instead see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I agree with Strawberry here. This should be solvable in sql. You could add the table scheme to make things easier for whoever wants to answer.

Comment: I understand, maybe sql is a better option indeed. I updated my question with the information to reproduce a simplified schema similar to my db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method has quadratic n^2 performance as number of queries multiples by number of events and attendances.

A first step to reduce quantity of queries could be extracting this query from the innermost loop

```
Attendance::where('student_id', $enrollment->student_id)->where('event_id', $event->id)->count() == 0
```

and fetch attendance upfront

```
public function getMissingAttendanceAttribute()
{
    $eventsWithMissingAttendanceCount = 0;

    $eventsIDs = $this->events_with_expected_attendance->pluck('id');
    $studentIDs = $this->enrollments->pluck('student_id');

    // Collection of attendances
    $attendances = Attendance::whereIn('student_id', $studentIDs)
        ->whereIn('event_id', $eventsIDs)
        ->get();


    // loop through every event supposed to have attendance
    foreach ($this->events_with_expected_attendance as $event)
    {
        // loop through every student
        foreach ($this->enrollments as $enrollment)
        {
            $hasNotAttended = $attendances->where('student_id', $enrollment->student_id)
                ->where('event_id', $event->id)
                ->isEmpty();

            if ($hasNotAttended) {
                $eventsWithMissingAttendanceCount++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $eventsWithMissingAttendanceCount;
}
```

That should improve performance because number of queries doesn't scale with number of events and enrollments but remains constant.

For example you could extract `$hasNotAttended` to a method of Enrollment model.

```
public function getMissingAttendanceAttribute()
{
    $eventsWithMissingAttendanceCount = 0;

    $eventsIDs = $this->events_with_expected_attendance->pluck('id');
    $studentIDs = $this->enrollments->pluck('student_id');

    // Collection of attendances
    $attendances = Attendance::whereIn('student_id', $studentIDs)
        ->whereIn('event_id', $eventsIDs)
        ->get();


    // loop through every event supposed to have attendance
    foreach ($this->events_with_expected_attendance as $event)
    {
        // loop through every student
        foreach ($this->enrollments as $enrollment)
        {
            // pass preloaded attendances.
            // alternatively you could preload this relationship then no need to pass $attendances
            if ($enrollment->hasNotAttended($event->id, $attendances)) {
                $eventsWithMissingAttendanceCount++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $eventsWithMissingAttendanceCount;
}
```

Then you could extend `$this->enrollments` collection https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#extending-collections by extracting the following.

```
    if ($enrollment->hasNotAttended($event->id, $attendances)) {
        $eventsWithMissingAttendanceCount++;
        break;
    }
```

So, it would be simplified to

```
public function getMissingAttendanceAttribute()
{
    $eventsWithMissingAttendanceCount = 0;

    $eventsIDs = $this->events_with_expected_attendance->pluck('id');
    $studentIDs = $this->enrollments->pluck('student_id');

    // Collection of attendances
    $attendances = Attendance::whereIn('student_id', $studentIDs)
        ->whereIn('event_id', $eventsIDs)
        ->get();


    // loop through every event supposed to have attendance
    foreach ($this->events_with_expected_attendance as $event)
    {
        if ($this->enrollments->hasNotAttended($event->id, $attendances)) {
            $eventsWithMissingAttendanceCount++;
        }
    }

    return $eventsWithMissingAttendanceCount;
}
```

Comment: Great solution! Thank you for your help and detailed explanation. I understood the benefits of your approach and I updated my code accordingly. Indeed, the number of DB queries is greatly reduced with your solution. It's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`enrollments` (for example) is a many:many mapping table.  The schema definition you have is very inefficient.  This gives several tips on improving performance in this area:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table